# What is the relation C-i and tab in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

When I bind a function to `C-i`. It seems that `tab` is bound to the function.
Why does it happens? Is it recognized same key in Emacs?

Comment: That's the escape code for `tab`. I.e. in older terminals there weren't always a tab key, so in order to type a tab character the combination of `control` and `i` was used. Similarly, `C-m` is the equivalent of `enter` - seems like a little bit of waste of the keybindings, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They happen to be linked in the default setup,
but it doesn't have to be this way:

```
(keyboard-translate ?\C-i ?\C-j)
```

Now `C-i` will do a newline, while `tab` will still indent.

Comment: interesting, why do they translate `C-i` to `TAB` instead of just binding `C-i` to the `indent line` function?

Comment: I think it's because C-i and TAB are same in bash, and they and to keep things consistent.

Comment: Historical reasons. In a plain terminal, the TAB key sent the same key code as Ctrl-i.

Comment: Thanks all! I decided to use keyboard-translate and hyper key like `(keyboard-translate ?\C-i ?\H-i)`.

Comment: What has been said in the comments above is correct, but incomplete. It's not just about `bash` or plain terminals. The fact is that the ASCII control character "TAB" (aka "horizontal tab", aka "HT") ***is*** the same character as `C-i`, that is, Control I. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character.

Answer (score 3):

Hitting TAB on a text terminal sends the `C-i` code (which is the ascii char named TAB) to the application, so under a tty `C-i` and TAB are usually indistinguishable.
Emacs by default preserves this equivalence in GUI environments by mapping the `tab` event to `C-i` when there's no binding for `tab` (this is done in `function-key-map`).  So most packages should bind their commands to the TAB char (i.e. `C-i`) rather than to the `tab` event, so that it works equally well under a tty or under a GUI.  But if you want to distinguish the two, it's very easy: just bind the command you want to the `tab` event and the mapping from `tab` to `C-i` won't happen any more.

Comment: Thanks for your info! I'd go with distinguishable way.